# urllib.request error 500 python 3.3.3

Tags: python, web-services

I created an algorithm which consumes the web service of the local bank using `url lib.request` in Python 3.3.3, but when I run it it gives out an error.

The error is the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    tipo_de_cambio()
    File "/Users/admin/Documents/TEC/Taller Programación/tdc.py", line 13, in tipo_de_cambio
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(request,data)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 138, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 375, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 487, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 413, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 347, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 495, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

And the program I coded is the following:

```
    import datetime
    import urllib.request
    from urllib.error import HTTPError
    from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

    def tipo_de_cambio():
        a = 0
        fecha = datetime.date.today()
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'tcIndicador':'318', 'tcFechaInicio':fecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), 'tcFechaFinal':fecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), 'tcNombre':"Usuario", 'tnSubNiveles':'N'})
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        request = urllib.request.Request('http://indicadoreseconomicos.bccr.fi.cr/indicadoreseconomicos/WebServices/wsIndicadoresEconomicos.asmx?op=ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML')
        request.add_header("POST","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(request,data)
        data = f.read().decode('utf-8')
        dom = parseString(data)
        xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('NUM_VALOR')[0].toxml()
        xmlData = xmlTag.replace('<NUM_VALOR>','').replace('</NUM_VALOR>','')
        a = float(xmlData)
        return(a)
```

The bank's web service url is: http://indicadoreseconomicos.bccr.fi.cr/indicadoreseconomicos/WebServices/wsIndicadoresEconomicos.asmx?op=ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML

Can someone tell me why I get this error?

Comment: what is data supposed to be doing? That  is causing your error

Comment: as i was explained, data is filling the information forms inside the web service to access the information I need

Comment: The request you want is a GET not a POST, isn't it? You wan to retrieve information, send information?

Comment: I want to retrieve information, so should I change the POST for a GET? (excuse my ignorance, I am just recently starting with Python)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import urllib.request
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

fecha = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
base_url = 'http://indicadoreseconomicos.bccr.fi.cr/indicadoreseconomicos/WebServices/wsIndicadoresEconomicos.asmx/ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML?tcIndicador={tcIndicador}&tcFechaInicio={tcFechaInicio}&tcFechaFinal={tcFechaFinal}&tcNombre={tcNombre}&tnSubNiveles={tnSubNiveles}'
data = {
    'tcIndicador':'318', 
    'tcFechaInicio':fecha,
    'tcFechaFinal':fecha, 
    'tcNombre':"Usuario", 
    'tnSubNiveles':'N'
}

result = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url.format(**data)).read()


dom = parseString(result)
xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('NUM_VALOR')[0].toxml()
xmlData = xmlTag.replace('<NUM_VALOR>','').replace('</NUM_VALOR>','')
a = float(xmlData)
return(a)
```

From here you can use your approach to parse xml .

Comment: so from there I just 'paste' my code and it should work?

Comment: It gives me a "list index out of range" error. I used the lines from "dom = parseString(data)" downwards

Comment: Fixed `base_url` typo.

Comment: I came across lxml doing research, but when i spoke to the professor, he told us that we were not allowed to use it, as well as the suds module

Comment: This xml is weird. Sorry, can't help from here.